# Node creation fields in blocks

Tags: display-suite, nodes

I am using [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) for node creation, but would like to extend this by also using blocks provided by theme to put several fields inside them too (sidebar left and right).

How to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to enable the Display Suite Extras module. (comes with display suite)

Go to manage display, scroll all the way down. Click on custom fields, add a block field.

[image]

Comment: That is for display. I am looking for node creation solution.